# Automatically Start Microsoft Reporting Services after a Restart

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, server

I have a VM running on a server, and, among other things, I have Microsoft Reporting Services running on it, as is used by one of my websites.

The thing is, there are times when the server restarts, and when it does, MRS does not automatically start running again; I have to manually start the service. Is there a way to configure MRS to start automatically after restarting the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Services in Control Panel, and find Microsoft Reporting Services.  Right click it, and go to `Properties`.  In the dialog that will appear, you'll see `Startup Type`.  Ensure that it is set to `Automatic`.